# how to get page contents

Tags: php, dom, web-crawler

I'm trying to make a recent news like functionality for my site. For this i've made a web crawler and have being able to collect links from a page up till now by doing the following

```
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
$dom->preserveWhiteSpaces = false;
$linksToStore = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($linksToStore as $tag){
    $links[$tag->getAttribute('href')]= $tag->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

how can i get contents from the pages pointed by those links related to a particular domain which in my case is 'Medical'??

Answer (score 0):

Use this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ library to extract contents from the page. The selector works same as of jQuery, which makes it very familier and efficient to extract the contents.

Also, check this http://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications to know more